SQL query to output values from a different column based on a field in a different column with the same values
I have added 1 original sample (69688) with 1 duplicate sample and 1 original sample (69672) and amended my query. With these changes my current output is as follows:

My query for this is:
select s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER as firstSamp, s2.SAMPLE_NUMBER as secSamp from SAMPLE s1, SAMPLE s2 
where s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER <> s2.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
and s1.ORIGINAL_SAMPLE = s2.ORIGINAL_SAMPLE 
and s2.SAMPLE_NAME = 'DUP' 
and s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER in (69672,69675,69676,69690,69688)
order by s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER desc

I want the following output: so that each sample can compare with the other sample based on the field called original sample. Each sample should compare with the other 2 sample only once for example 69672 should compare with 69675 and 69676, then 69675 should compare with 69676 as shown in the output in the picture below.

Thanks and regards

How does the original table magically transformed to the output table???

Add more sample table data, e.g. one OrigSamp with 1 extra sample. and one with 3 extra samples.

Try This
Select Distinct(origSample) as OSamp,DupSample as DSamp from(
Select s1.origSample, s2.DupSample
from #Sample s1 inner join #Sample s2
on s1.OrigSample <> s2.DupSample)a
where OrigSample <> DupSample
and OrigSample = 69672
order by OrigSample


DISTINCT is no function, so it shouldn't be used in braces

I have added 1 original sample with 1 duplicate sample and 1 original sample with 2 duplicate samples. I have also updated my original query and the images as per the current and the expected output. Please can someone help with amending my query to achieve the expected output.
